# find the direction of maximum increase of $f(x, y)$ starting from the point $P(1, 1)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x, y) = xye^{x^
α−y^
α}$

Let $α > 1$, find the direction of maximum increase of $f(x, y)$ starting from the point $P(1, 1)$,
using the parametric equation of a line.

I know that the gradient evaluated at $P$ points towards the maximal direction of increase.  But if I find the gradient don't I get 'two' slope? I am not sure howw to find such an equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increase in a function value in a point $P=(x_0,y_0)$ in a specific direction $\vec v$ with $|\vec v|=1$ can be evaluated as $$\nabla f(x_0,y_0)^T\cdot \vec v$$(a proof can be obtained easily by only expanding the terms). Hence the maximum increase is obtained in direction of $\vec v={\nabla f(x_0,y_0)\over |\nabla f(x_0,y_0)|}$ and is as much as $|\nabla f(x_0,y_0)|$.

Comment: Ok but what is the equaation ofthe line in such a case?

Comment: It becomes $${x=x_0+t\cdot\nabla f(x_0,y_0)_x\\y=y_0+t\cdot\nabla f(x_0,y_0)_y\\z=f(x_0,y_0)+t\cdot\nabla f(x_0,y_0)_z}$$

Comment: Thank you, now it clear